# How to create a simple window with 3 frames and dynamic layout in Python3 / tkinter with grid?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I am exploring tkinter in Python3 and have just started my first GUI project. I am trying to use the grid positioning system and 3 frames to create a simple layout like this:

- **Top frame:** tool bar, some buttons, maybe a search field (should be always visible and stick to the top of the window and extend all across left to right).
- **Main frame:** treeview, intended to retrieve values from a database (should stick to the top, right below the top frame, expanding from left to right, and should also expand to take all the space left by top and bottom frames).
- **Bottom frame:** data entry form, status bar... (should stick to the bottom of the window, expanding from left to right, and leave space to the main frame.

I have been messing around with frames and weights and it seems to be always something wrong. If I resize the window small enough, the main frame hides partially the top frame. If I enlarge the window, the main frame and the treeview does not expand all the way down as intended. Can anyone please help?

Here is my code as I have it right now:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
# encoding: utf-8
"""
docstring
"""

import sys
import os
import os.path
import csv
import re
from platform import node


from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


__app_name__ = "APP NAME"
__version__ = "0.0.1"


def add_remessa():
    pprint("REMESSA")


def click_btn_hoje():
    print("HOJE")


root = Tk()
root.title(__app_name__+" "+__version__)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

topframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
topframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, E, W))
topframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
topframe.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
topframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
topframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(N, W, E))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

bottomframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
bottomframe.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=(W, E, S))
bottomframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
bottomframe.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
bottomframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
bottomframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


def NovaRemessa():
    print("Nova remessa!")
def EditarRemessa():
    print("Editar")
def About():
    print("This is a simple example of a menu")
def painelAddRemessa():
        print("Mostrar painel de introdução de nova remessa")


btn_quit = ttk.Button(topframe, text="+", command=painelAddRemessa)
btn_quit.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky=E+N)

btn_quit = ttk.Button(topframe, text="  Sair  ", command=exit)
btn_quit.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E+N)

# Data entry form
obj_num = StringVar()
destin = StringVar()
cobr = StringVar()
dias = StringVar()
vols = StringVar()

ttk.Label(bottomframe, text="Nº Objeto").grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W+S)
text_input_obj = ttk.Entry(bottomframe,textvariable=obj_num, width=13)
text_input_obj.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W+S)
text_input_obj.focus_set()

ttk.Label(bottomframe, text="Destinatário").grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky=W+S)
text_input_dest = ttk.Entry(bottomframe, textvariable=destin, width=25)
text_input_dest.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W+S)

ttk.Label(bottomframe, text="Cobrança").grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=W+E+S)
text_input_cobr = ttk.Entry(bottomframe, textvariable=cobr, width=7)
text_input_cobr.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky=W+E+S)

ttk.Label(bottomframe, text="Dias").grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=W+E+S)
text_input_dias = ttk.Entry(bottomframe, textvariable=dias, width=4)
text_input_dias.grid(row=6, column=3, sticky=W+E+S)

ttk.Label(bottomframe, text="Volumes").grid(row=5, column=4, sticky=W+E+S)
text_input_vols = ttk.Entry(bottomframe, textvariable=vols, width=5)
text_input_vols.grid(row=6, column=4, sticky=W+E+S)

# Botões
btn_add = ttk.Button(bottomframe, text="  Adicionar  ", command=add_remessa).grid(row=6, column=6,sticky=W+E+S)


ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Nº de remessas: XXXX").grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Valor a cobrar: XXXXXX").grid(row=2, columnspan=2, column=2)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Recebido: XXXXX").grid(row=2, column=4)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Depositar: XXXXXXX").grid(row=2, column=6, sticky=E)

tree = ttk.Treeview(mainframe, selectmode='extended')
tree['columns'] = ('ID', 'Dias', 'Destinatário', 'Estado', 'Objeto nº', 'Cobr.', 'Chq.rec.', 'Depositar')
tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=7, sticky=N+W+E+S)
tree.column('#0', anchor=W, minwidth=0, stretch=0, width=0)
tree.column('ID', anchor=W, minwidth=30, stretch=1, width=30)
tree.column('Dias', minwidth=30, stretch=1, width=30)
tree.column('Destinatário', minwidth=100, stretch=1, width=200)
tree.column('Estado', minwidth=100, stretch=1, width=180)
tree.column('Objeto nº', minwidth=50, stretch=1, width=80)
tree.column('Cobr.', minwidth=60, stretch=1, width=60)
tree.column('Chq.rec.', minwidth=80, stretch=1, width=80)
tree.column('Depositar', anchor=E, minwidth=80, stretch=1, width=80)
tree.heading('ID', text="ID")
tree.heading('Dias', text="Dias")
tree.heading('Destinatário', text="Destinatário")
tree.heading('Estado', text="Estado")
tree.heading('Objeto nº', text="Objeto nº")
tree.heading('Cobr.', text="Cobr.")
tree.heading('Chq.rec.', text="Chq.rec.")
tree.heading('Depositar', text="Depositar")

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=1, pady=1)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need all that code to illustrate the problem. Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry! I have just removed some parts of the code that I believe were not related to the problem I am trying to solve now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are neglecting to do a couple of things. First, you are giving all of the weight to row 0 of the root window. Since you want the main area to take up all the extra space you need to give the weight to row 1.

Second, you aren't giving any weight to the rows and columns inside the main frame. Since you want the tree (I assume) to fill the space, you must give the row and column of the tree a weight.

---

A word of advice: don't try to solve all of your layout problems at once. Start your program over, and create just the three frames in root: top, middle and bottom. Temporarily give each one of them a distinctive color so you can distinguish them. Then, lay them out with pack or grid, and make sure when you resize the window that those areas grow and shrink appropriately.

Only after you have those three areas behaving properly should you attempt to add widgets to only one of those frames. Make sure when you resize the window that everything continues to work. Then add the next frame, again making sure it is all working before continuing to the next problem.

You should also consider using `pack` for part of your GUI. `pack` is an arguably better choice when you have things stacked top-to-bottom or side-to-side. If I were writing this code I'd use `pack` for the three main frames, and `grid` for the widgets inside each frame.

Comment: You are right. I will start over and this time I will explore pack. It's all very new to me and I am getting a bit overwhelmed by this. Still trying to figure out how to do simple things...

Comment: I didn't know we could use both methods, pack and grid, in the same window. I read somewhere that it was not recommended.

Comment: @Victor: the best way to figure out how to do simple things is to start by doing simple things. Start with _just_ the frames. Get those working before trying to fill them in. If you try to build a whole layout at once it can make the job more difficult.

Comment: @Victor: you can use both `pack` and `grid` in the same _program_. The only time you can't mix them is when two or more widgets share the same parent.